# PHPunit is erroring out with Exception: Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed even though it shouldn't

Tags: php, phpunit

I have an odd error.  Trying to implement PHPunit in a legacy code base.  In the code base there's a bit of logic around setting up the include path which is messing up phpunit and I can't see how.

The code:

```
$includePath = (realpath((__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php')) . PATH_SEPARATOR);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__));
foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
    if ('.' == $fileInfo->getFilename()) {
        $includePath .= ($fileInfo->getPath() . PATH_SEPARATOR);
    }  
}
set_include_path($includePath);
```

If I hardcode the $includePath then it works just fine.  However, with this code in my bootstrap file I get the error:

> Exception: Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed

On every test.  Which to me doesn't make sense as I'm not trying to use the RecursiveDirectoryIterator anywhere inside the tests, and i'm not trying to serialize any of the RecursiveDirectoryIterator files either.  It's very odd.

My Unit Tests look like:

```
class ReportTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {



    public function testAssertTrue() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

and I run phpunit like:

```
phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php tests
```

The bootstrap has those lines at the top (the include path setup), and then includes other stuff like our db connection, etc.

The error looks like:

```
$ phpunit --bootstrap tests/test_bootstrap.php tests
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

EEEEEEEEE

Time: 340 ms, Memory: 19.00Mb

There were 9 errors:

1) ReportTest::testAssertTrue
Exception: Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed

.... etc
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: none it just says: There were 8 errors:  1)ReportTest::testAssertTrue \n Exception: Serialization of 'SplFileInfo' is not allowed

Comment: It doesn't even give an error above in the tests.  If it gave a line number :) i'd have something to go off of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is returning the `SplFileInfo`, for the `foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo)`.

Is that code in the global namespace, outside of a function/class? PHPunit will backup and then restore the global variables - set with `backupGlobals` in the phpunit.xml file. The [code that performs that backup](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/global-state/blob/23af31f402993cfd94e99cbc4b782e9a78eb0e97/src/Snapshot.php#L313) in recent versions at least, appears from that code to do a `unserialize(serialize($value));` which the `SplFileInfo` class doesn't like.

If you can put that setup into a class, and out of the global space, it would not attempt to 'back it up'.

Or maybe just `unset($iterator);` when you are done with it?

Comment: `unset($iterator)` will not be enough to solve the issue. `$fileInfo` needs to unset, too. After all, it's the `SplFileInfo` object that PHPUnit cannot serialize.

Comment: Let me check this answer, it makes perfect sense, i'll accept shortly if it works.  Thanks

Comment: Sebastian is right, $fileInfo had to be unset as well.  But thank you both for the answer.  We had tried unset($iterator).  Also turning off backupGlobals works :)

Comment: Note - putting it in it's own class as a static method fixed the problem as well, and is a cleaner solution anyway.

Comment: Same problem, solution worked for me. Moved code into a function and it's ok now.